# Need Help formulating an SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySql 5.5. Let's start by looking at a sample of my table:

```
pickupid    pickuplocation      Date1       Date2       Date3       Date4
1           Collingwood         1328079600  1330585200  1333260000  1335852000
2           Varsity             1328079600  1330585200  1333260000  1335852000
3           Canmore             1328079600  1330585200  1333260000  1335852000
4           Westbrook           1328079600  1330585200  1333260000  1335852000
```

I need  a query which will select only those dates which are in the *future*. If a date is in the past the query must skip over it. I have tried using Select with Have, Or, Where & AND. My queries fail because if one of the dates  happens to be in the past then the whole query comes back with zero results.  Yes, I know that if I orientated my table around the other way ie with locations in the columns and dates in the rows it could make it easier - I've tried that,  but I run into other problems as my HTML report has to accommodate over 50 locations,  but only 4 dates.

Many Many Thanks for All your Help !!

Comment: Do you mind sharing the query you have tried so far and the output?

Comment: Pseudo... SELECT * FROM table WHERE date1 > now() or date 2 > now() etc...?

Comment: You MUST provide an example of the output you want.  You haven't given enough information, and what you have provided can be interpreted in several ways: (1) all rows that have ANY date in the future; (2) the same, but return null for dates in the past; (3) all rows that have ALL dates in the future

Comment: Where is the code? Where is the output sample?

Comment: Agreed. We need to see a) the actual query b) a sample of the actual results and c) what the results should be instead and *why*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's not a lot of detail about what you're trying to get, I'm just taking a guess, but, the below query will return all results where one of the dates is in the future, only the date columns with dates in the future will have data in them, the others will be set to NULL.

You can then exclude the null dates in your processing ...

Is this what you're going for?

```
SELECT
    pickupid,
    pickuplocation,
    IF(Date1 > NOW(),Date1,NULL) AS Date1,
    IF(Date2 > NOW(),Date2,NULL) AS Date2,
    IF(Date3 > NOW(),Date3,NULL) AS Date3,
    IF(Date4 > NOW(),Date4,NULL) AS Date4
FROM
    locations_table
WHERE
    Date1 > NOW() 
    OR Date2 > NOW()
    OR Date3 > NOW()
    OR Date4 > NOW()
```